# Setting up a chroot sftp on debian server

Tags: ssh, debian, sftp, chroot

I'm trying to allow a user "user" to access my server by either sftp or ssh. I want to jail them into a directory with chroot. I read the instructions [here](http://undeadly.org/cgi?action=article&sid=20080220110039) however it does not work.
I did the following:

1. useradd user
2. modify /etc/ssh/sshd_config and added

   `Match User user`

   `ForceCommand internal-sftp`

   `ChrootDirectory /home/duke/aa/smart`
   to the bottom of the file
3. changed the subsystem line to `Subsystem       sftp    internal-sftp`
4. restarted sshd with `/etc/init.d/ssh restart`
5. logged in with ssh as user "user" with PuTTY

Putty says "Server unexpectly closed the connection".

Why is this and how can it be fixed?

**EDIT**

Following the suggestions below, I've made the bottom of sshd_config look like:

```
Match User user
   ChrootDirectory /tmp
```

yet no change. I do get a password OK but I cannot connect via ssh nor sftp. What gives?

Comment: If you use `ForceCommand`, then you can't use `ssh` to connect.  You can only connect via sftp.  Were you connecting with sftp, and wrote the wrong thing for step 5?

Comment: @Zoredache I cannot connect with sftp nor ssh

Comment: See my response in this: http://serverfault.com/questions/265185/how-do-i-setup-sftp-for-sites-without-giving-shell-access/265194#265194

Answer (score 1):

The directory that you set as your chroot must be owned by root and have 755 permissions.

This is what I use for my setup

```
Match user sftpuser
 ChrootDirectory /home/sftpuser
    AllowTCPForwarding no
    X11Forwarding no
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

in /home

```
drwxr-xr-x   5 root    users 4096 Jan 29 10:31 sftpuser
```

in /home/sftpuser

```
drwx------ 2 sftpuser users 4096 Jan 29 10:52 sftpuser
```

This chroot's them to the /home/sftpuser directory, but since they have no permission to write into it I create the second sftpuser directory for them to write to.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in `ChrootDirectory /home/duke/aa/smart`. The problem is related to permissions. The user through which you are trying to log into the box doesnot have the executable permission I think. Can you once try changing this to some directory like `/tmp` where every user has full permission.

Comment: I have tried this but no change. What could be the problem?

Comment: Can u tried sshing using increased verbosity option. You can try the ssh with `-v` option of verbosity and find out where it is failing.

Comment: @KevinDuke: Can you check the logs of server `/var/log/secure` once. Is there any kind of clue that you can get there.

Comment: `root@Rx:~# ssh -V`
`OpenSSH_5.5p1 Debian-6+squeeze2, OpenSSL 0.9.8o 01 Jun 2010`
`/var/log/secure: No such file or directory`

Comment: @KevinDuke: I mean you need to ssh into the server from linux client using the command: `ssh -v user@serverip`. Note the v is small letter not the capital letter.

Answer (score 0):

Check your /var/log/auth.log for ssh errors.

It's probably a permissions error.  The chroot directory must be owned by **root**.

FYI, my working config looks like this (I prefer using group access instead of user access):

```
Subsystem       sftp    internal-sftp

AllowGroups sshusers sftponly

Match group sftponly
  ChrootDirectory %h
  X11Forwarding no
  AllowTcpForwarding no
  ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

Answer (score 0):

SSHD is very strict about chroot permissions; I found a solution that worked for me [here](https://serverfault.com/a/691451). Essentially, the ChrootDirectory *and all of its parent directories* need to be owned by root and have 755 permissions. You can get the permissions using the command `namei -l /path/to/chrootdirectory`. In my case, `/tmp` has 777 permissions, so I was getting a `client_loop: send disconnect: Broken pipe` error when trying to connect. I moved the chroot to `/opt/chrootjail` and it started working.