# SSH - ChrootDirectory not working

Tags: ssh, debian, sftp, chroot

I am trying to chroot a "test" user (group sftp) to /home/test. I've added the following lines at the end of my sshd_config:

```
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp

Match User test
    ChrootDirectory /home/test
    X11Forwarding no
    AllowTcpForwarding no
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

`home` and `test`directories have 755 permissions and are owned by root. I have also tried with `ChrootDirectory /home`.

```
root@Debian:/# namei -l /home/test
f: /home/test
drwxrwxrwx root root /
drwxr-xr-x root root home
drwxr-xr-x root root test
```

I am unable to connect to the server via SFTP or SSH (whether I include `Subsystem sftp internal-sftp` and `ForceCommand internal-sftp` or not). As soon as I log in I get the following message:

```
Write failed: Broken pipe
```

... and the following is appended to auth.log:

```
May 12 13:48:29 Reach sshd[25503]: Accepted password for test from 192.168.0.10 port 51058 ssh2
May 12 13:48:29 Reach sshd[25503]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user test by (uid=0)
May 12 13:48:29 Reach sshd[25505]: fatal: bad ownership or modes for chroot directory component "/"
May 12 13:48:29 Reach sshd[25503]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user test
```

Apparently the problem is it's trying to chroot to "/" when it should be "/home/test". What am I missing ? I've left the rest of sshd_config to default values, and there is no other ChrootDirectory directive...

Thank you.

Comment: Can you include the output of `namei -l /home/test` in your question?

Comment: Edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your permissions on `/` are too open.
I wonder how you ended up with that.
That should be `0755`.
So you'll need to change that.

The rest looks OK.

Comment: Ahhh indeed, thank you, I didn't even bother checking... The server is a Synology NAS, I guess the Synology file server must have messed with the permissions somehow. Much work to do now...